# Future Quotes on the S&P 500 Index

Tags: portfolio-management, futures

I am looking at the following quotes of the futures prices of the S&P 500:
         http://finance.yahoo.com/q/fc?bypass=true&s=ESM16.CME&ltr=1
The way I read this, the market thinks that there will no increase in the S&P 500 for the next year. That does not seem right to me. Is there something I am missing?

Bob

Comment: Have you taken into account dividends?

Comment: The futures prices are not based on expectations of where the market will be, but on the spot price, the interest rate and the dividends

Comment: Msitt,I have taken into account dividends and therefore if I buy a basket of stocks representing the S&P 500 and I hold it for a year and the S&P 500 remains flat, I understand that my return will be positive ( say 3% ) because of dividends. However, that does not seem very good to me.